# How to convert multiple array in json using Highchart?

Tags: php, arrays

I have one array as follows

```
    Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [rvoltage_data] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 1466773140000
                            [1] => 231.81
                        )

                    [yvoltage_data] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 1466773140000
                            [1] => 229.95
                        )

                    [bvoltage_data] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 1466773140000
                            [1] => 231.44
                        )

                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [rvoltage_data] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 1466773200000
                            [1] => 231.81
                        )

                    [yvoltage_data] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 1466773200000
                            [1] => 229.95
                        )

                    [bvoltage_data] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 1466773200000
                            [1] => 231.44
                        )

                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [rvoltage_data] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 1466773500000
                            [1] => 231.81
                        )

                    [yvoltage_data] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 1466773500000
                            [1] => 231.32
                        )

                    [bvoltage_data] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 1466773500000
                            [1] => 231.44
                        )

                )
)
```

Above array I want to convert into below array

```
   [rvoltage_data] => Array (
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1466773140000
            [1] => 231.81
        ),
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1466773140000
            [1] => 231.81
        )       
)
[yvoltage_data] => Array (
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1466773140000
            [1] => 231.81
        ),
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1466773140000
            [1] => 231.81
        )       
)
[bvoltage_data] => Array (
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1466773140000
            [1] => 231.81
        ),
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1466773140000
            [1] => 231.81
        )   
)
```

Is it possible to convert above format. If yes please help me. I try to solve this but not getting any answer. I don't know how to solve this please suggest me.

Comment: by [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)

Comment: I tried this but graph not plotting @Rishi

Comment: can you share which form of json is working and which is not ?

Comment: json_encode will work, probably the way you are calling your variables are wrong

Comment: json response like this [rvoltage_data:[1466773140000,231.81],yvoltage_data:[1466773140000,229.95],bvoltage_data:[1466773140000,231.44]] @Rishi

Comment: But in highchart required http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/line-basic/

Comment: I think that you need to preprocess your data so it will be possible to use them in Highcharts. Here you can find simple example how you can preprocess your data: http://jsfiddle.net/0ohdxsgp/2/

Answer (score 0):

1) Ok, the first step is to restructure your array. You can do that by iterating over the elements of your old `$array` and re-assign the values to a new array `$result`.

```
$result = '';

foreach($array as $index => $data)
{
    $result['rvoltage_data'][] = $data['rvoltage_data'];
    $result['yvoltage_data'][] = $data['yvoltage_data'];
    $result['bvoltage_data'][] = $data['bvoltage_data'];
}

var_dump($result);
```

2)  The second step is to output the array as JSON by using `json_encode`, so that you can embed the content into the Highchart Javascript as data. `JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK` is used to get rid of the quotes around the numbers, which you would normally get, when using this function.

```
echo json_encode($result, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
```

3) Last step: get data into Highcharts.

There are numerous examples on SO and on the offical HighCharts site,
e.g. http://www.highcharts.com/docs/working-with-data/custom-preprocessing#3

You could for instance "grab" the data via a jQuery `getJSON()` request from your PHP file: "getData.php". The important part is where you assign incoming data to the Highcharts options array of your chart. `console.log()` is used to display the incoming JSON data in the Browser console for debugging purposes.

```
$.getJSON('getData.php', function(data) {
    // debug: show data in browser console 
    console.log(data);

    // assign incoming data to the Highcharts options array of your chart
    options.series[0].data = data;
    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
});
```